# Why does Google Chrome fail to provide a checksum

Tags: google-chrome, security, download

Alright, I may be a bit uneducated when it comes to this subject but I have a genuine curiosity about why Google does not provide a checksum along with a gpg signature with their Google Chrome download. In fact I have never even seen a checksum anywhere on Google.com.

I understand the download is via an HTTPS connection, but correct me if I'm wrong it would still be possible to inject a malicious download right? I read somewhere that [exit nodes for VPN's were found to have injected executables](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/10/27/tor_exit_node_mashes_malware_into_downloads/).

Then just recently, Linux Mint had their website hacked because of a faulty Wordpress configuration, and the linux mint [ISO was swapped with one containing a backdoor for someones DDOS swarm](http://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/news/cybercrime-and-digital-threats/linux-mint-website-hacked-iso-downloads-replaced-with-a-backdoor).

Windows updates, apple updates, Ubuntu's apt-get all have signature signing and verification of packages.

But Google of all companies doesn't have even a checksum on their download page.

Why is this? Is there really any risk for end-users download Chrome?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows installers are signed using Authenticode (X.509), which is verified natively by Windows itself. Automatic updates (delivered using Omaha) are also signed using X.509.

The [Linux repositories](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) are signed using GPG – when you first download the `google-chrome-current.deb` over HTTPS, it automatically adds the updates repository to sources.list and installs its signing key to your apt configuration (see `/opt/google/chrome/cron/`).

(I wouldn't say that's very bad. Consider this: If you think an attacker can inject a fake download... Why couldn't they inject fake "checksums" as well? If you cannot trust that you downloaded the right `.deb` from https://google.com, then likewise you couldn't trust that you obtained the right PGP keys from https://google.com either.)

> I understand the download is via an HTTPS connection, but correct me if I'm wrong it would still be possible to inject a malicious download right?

Generally no. That's... kind of what HTTPS is supposed to prevent.

There are two possibilities though:

- If you start with `http://www.google.com/chrome` and expect to be automatically redirected to HTTPS, an attacker can strip this redirect and force you to stay on the HTTP version.

  To avoid that, make sure you *only* visit the download pages over HTTPS; there might be some Tor configuration that you could use to block HTTP (tcp/80) entirely. (I know Tor has a port whitelist for exit nodes, but it would certainly be useful to have one for clients as well...)
- If you open a HTTPS website but the attacker intercepts your connection (MITM), the browser will warn you about a certificate error (since the attacker cannot get a "real" certificate for `google.com`), but many people will just blindly "click through" those warnings without even looking.

  To avoid that, don't bypass those browser security warnings.

The largest browsers (even IE, I think?) now come with `google.com` in their "HSTS preload" lists, which force the browser to always use HTTPS *and* prevent the user from bypassing certificate errors. So it should safeguard against such mistakes.

Comment: The only way to 100% avoid attacks is to use a [**DNSSEC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) download server, the autorithy of the download+checkum must  be trusted... Example: conecting `google.com` at China is perhaps corruped at DNS level...  Even in other countries, as DNS of google is not a DNSSEC and DNSSEC of UBUNTU have warnings.. see https://zonemaster.iis.se/

Answer (score 0):

A checksum would provide a baseline verification that a given target (version, os, arch, etc) is valid, which is generally a good thing and is universally accepted as best practice; just because a given best practice "could" be compromised, doesn't mean that we shouldn't follow it. Even if it were the case that the cksum value was forged, it would be unrealistic to consider that as anything but temporary and verifying the signature would still fail; sure, maybe an attacker manages to swap out gpg keys, which would effect anyone downloading them after that point in time, from something like google.com/pubkey, but that wouldn't account for the copies of that public key that are shared widely, [as per design (see public key infrastructure)](https://www.ssh.com/academy/pki#:%7E:text=Public%20Key%20Infrastructure%20(PKI)%20is,a%20particular%20user%20or%20device).

The problem, for Google, with publicly providing a checksum, is that it would make it harder to herd users to a desired version. Take for example, the obviously shady hosting sites that offer past versions of tools that are no longer (purposefully) made available by the given publisher; they have no means of proving that the virus ridden download, being presented as valid, actually is. As I found out recently, you would have a hard time finding a valid, past-released version of chrome, because every download from everyone of those sites is compromised in some fashion. How do we know this? Because ad revenue requires quantifiable engagement, which a download site does not provide; what little they are making does not cover storage, bandwidth and developer overhead.